# A rustic, three story-Arabic bookstore

Tags: word-meaning

> ["A rustic, three story-Arabic bookstore in old Istanbul has become an anchor for many Syrians who have stayed put in Turkey but crave a taste of home"](http://www.haaretz.com/middle-east-news/1.712476)

What does **three story** refer to?

What does it mean by **A [rustic](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rustic_1), three story-Arabic store**?

- Note 04/05/16:

Our bookstores here only have racks of books, which are classified by their genres. So, I was not aware that a three-story bookstore is a bookstore that has three levels or floors. Thanks for everyone's response.

A bookstore in my country:

[image]

Comment: The bookstore is (1) rustic, (2) three stories and (3) Arabic. Three stories means three levels, or three floors.

Comment: @MaxW The bookstore only sells Arabic books? I don't think so because in the 3rd paragraph of that article, it is said: "Its weekly program includes music concerts and, starting soon, language exchanges in Arabic, English and Turkish. **Books are available in all three languages.**"

Answer (score 8):

The hyphen is in the wrong place, so it's a little hard to read.  It should be:

> A rustic, three-story Arabic bookstore in old Istanbul has become an anchor for many Syrians who have stayed put in Turkey but crave a taste of home.

It means that the Arabic bookstore is rustic and three stories high.  *Arabic bookstore* means that it is store which sells books in Arabic.  *Three-story* means that it has three levels or floors.  That is, two flights of stairs.  *Rustic* means:

> **a**. Lacking the refinement or elegance associated with urban life.
>   **b**. Charmingly simple or unsophisticated in a manner considered typical of country living.

<sub>(source: [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rustic) definition 2)</sub>

Comment: Can I just point out that we Brits like our buildings to have storeys with an **e**. A three-story bookshop would be a bookshop with a **very** limited catalog. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/storey

Comment: @JavaLatte: That is a good point, but it wasn't I who chose the words.

Comment: Thanks! Our bookstores here only have racks of books, which are classified by their genres. So, I didn't think that a three-story bookstore is a bookstore that has three levels or floors.

Comment: @Zondo, you stated "Arabic bookstore means that it is store which sells books in Arabic." No, the store doesn't only sell books in Arabic because in the 3rd paragraph of that article, it is said: "Its weekly program includes music concerts and, starting soon, language exchanges in Arabic, English and Turkish. **Books are available in all three languages**."

Comment: @Student Nobody said "Arabic books *only*". But obviously the author wants to point out that the store *does* sell books in Arabic with regard to the refugee situation.